# Crystal Report report with compact data

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have this kind of table

```
Name | Month | Usage
-------------------------

A    |  1    |  30 pcs

A    |  5    |  4 pcs

B    |  2    |  11 pcs

C    |  5    |  90 pcs
```

is it possible to create crystal report that looks like this in vb.net?

```
          |                    MONTH
  Name    | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec 
 =================================================================================
   A      | 30  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 4   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   

   B      | 0   | 11  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   

   C      | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 90  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a cross-tab object.